# Содержимое javax.xml.parsers.* вызывает вопросы

Tags: xml, java

В XML я новичок. изучаю пакет javax.xml.parsers. В этом пакете 4 класса. Интересуют DocumentBuilderFactory и DocumentBuilder. (SAX пока не трогаю).

1. вопрос по фабричному классу. Как я понял фабрика может загрузить сторонний класс и использовать его реализацию (метод newInstance(String factoryClassName, ClassLoader classLoader)). А что же делает метод newInstance() тот что без параметров ? загружает реализацию этой фабрики по умолчанию ?
2. вопрос по DocumentBuilder. В зависимости от реализации фабрика возвращает этот DocumentBuilder. Что это за объект, это и есть сам объект парсера? Если это так то кем он написан?
3. что за класс DOMParser ? Я в одной книжке обнаружил что автор работает напрямую с ним, безо всяких фабрик. И к тому же этот DOMPaser какойто странный - нельзя сосздать новый документ с его помощью.
4. что такое JAXP ? это библиотека для работы с XML на языке java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> А что же делает метод newInstance() тот что без параметров ?

Если возникает вопрос, что делает метод, логично начать с чтения [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance())

Для выбора реализации `DocumentBuilderFactory` используется следующий алгоритм:

1. Имя класса берется из значения системного свойства `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`.
2. Если оно не задано, проверяется значение свойства `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` в properties-файле `ib/jaxp.properties`
3. Если значение не задано и там, все jar-ники включенные в classpath проверяются на наличие файла META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.
4. Если и это не помогло, используется реализация по-умолчанию.

> Что это за объект, это и есть сам объект парсера? Если это так то кем он написан?

Да. Кем он написан, зависит от того, какую реализацию вы используете (см.выше). Очевидно, что дефолтная реализация написана Sun.

> DOMPaser какойто странный - нельзя сосздать новый документ с его помощью.

На то он и парсер, чтобы парсить существующий докумет.

> что такое JAXP ? это библиотека для работы с XML на языке java?

Упрощенно - да.

На самом деле это спецификация API для обработки XML, которая может быть реализована сторонними разработчиками в виде библиотек. Как обычно бывает в таких случаях, есть и стандартная реализация от Sun.

Comment: 1)странно - ведь DocumentBuilder и DOMParser являются парсерами, однако DOMParser не может создать новый Document.
2) и также очень странно что DOMParser не является наследником DocumentBuilder. :(
З.Ы. открыв реализацию DocumentBuilder обнаружил что DocumentBuilder делегирует DOMParser. наверное больше вопросов нет. Спасибо